# get a randomly picked background image to appear as the background image for a Div

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, developer

My HTML Contains

1)have js file contain java script function

```
function getRandomInt(min, max)
 {

  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;

}

document.getElementById("logoArea").className += " bg" + getRandomInt(1, 4);
```

---

2)in my html code having div like below

from  java script it takes random number then append  bg"Random number"(e.g.:- bg1) inside div class

```
**<header class="header">
<div id="logoArea" class="top-header clearfix container bg1">
</div>**

<header>
```

---

3)then css file

```
#logoArea.bg1 {
    background-image: url(../img/bgimages/bg1.png);
}
#logoArea.bg2 {
    background-image: url(../img/bgimages/bg2.png);
}
#logoArea.bg3 {
    background-image: url(../img/bgimages/bg3.png);
}
}
```

after that css files pulls images

I'm trying to get a randomly picked background image  to appear as the background image for a Div in USERCONTROL.

My Requirements Are:-The background in the header shall allow for random header backgrounds to be pulled from a Home Page Header Backgrounds picture library Pro-grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment but what is the problem you're having? What is wrong with the code you have? And when should the random background be applied to the div? Is it on load or some event?

```
<header class="header">
    <div id="logoArea" class="top-header clearfix container"></div>
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

document.getElementById("logoArea").style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/bgimages/bg" + getRandomInt(1,4)  + ".png)";
</script>
```

Comment: on load ,Don't know how to set random images programmatically,

Comment: are you using jQuery?

Comment: No, Not using Query , Requirement Mention in Question are given by clients and they wants user Control for that, Compulsory to use their java-script and

Comment: Where in SharePoint do you want this? Is this in a WebPart page? A custom page? Can you modify the entire page's HTML or just a part of it?

Comment: If they want user control then they want the user to be able to change the background instead of it doing onload?

Comment: every time when user refresh the pages ,  trying set random image for div

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24658/discussion-between-axay-and-imthenachoman).

Comment: can't chat right now. will follow up this evening.